# Reducing input voltage spikes on buck converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am using a buck converter to drop from 5V to 1.8V to be able to drive both of these voltage levels in a single design. The buck converter works correctly to generate a clean 1.8V supply, but the input side of the buck converter, the 5V side, is being contaminated with switching noise spikes of around 1.5 volts as a result of the buck converter being in the circuit. I have used the FT440A and AP3429 chips.

I have tried playing with the capacitance on the 5V input to the buck converter as well as adding diodes and inductors, but so far I have had no real effect on the spike amplitude. Is there a set of standard approaches to removing this sort of input noise that someone could highlight?

The default circuit is all that I am using with the exception of trying numerous modifications on the Vin side to get rid of the noise being seen:

[image]

Here are the input spikes that I see:

[image]

As far as layout is concerned, C1 is as close to Vin as possible. I have tried from 4.7 to 22uF capacitors. I also tried adding 3.3uH and 4.7uH inductors between before Vin.

Comment: Could you please add a schematic or diagram to back up your questions. We need to see the details of the design. SMPS are real finicky to build and have no noise on input or outputs. The board layout has to be near perfect.

Comment: The ESR of C1 is critical and the chief cause of actual spikes.   How confident are you that they are not measurement errors from probe ground inductance? Ask if you do not know how to measure spikes on 50 Ohms AC coupled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue was with the trace to C1 such that the capacitor was soldered in place but not actually connected between Vin and GND. The buck converter works fine as per the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

As with any o-scope measurements on switching regulator circuits you can get false indictaions of spikes if you do not use best practise when probing: -

[image]

The "bad measurement" technique is susceptible to induced voltages from the switching currents - the loop formed by the probe's earth connection in effect acts like a receiver for magnetic fields. The bigger the loop area, the more interference is picked up.

I'm not saying this is always to blame but it can be a very common mistake when probing high current/frequency circuits.

You can prove this by connecting the probe tip to the probe ground wire and, without making a physical connection to your regulator, move the loop around to see what you pick-up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the spikes are quite real. I tried your suggestion and there is no difference in the size of the spikes.

Comment: @Jason then you need to consider that your PCB layout is problematic. You are using a PCB? If you are using breadbaord then always expect problems like this. BTW what sort of signal size did you pick up with the probe shorted as per my last paragraph?

Comment: @Andyaka is correct, there is significant ripple current on the input to a buck converter, so the input capacitors have to be low ESR and the PCB layout has to have very low inductance from the drain of the top FET to the ground of the bottom FET or diode.  If all of  that is in order adding more capacitance will reduce the input ripple.  If it doesn't, then the PCB layout is problematic.

Comment: I am using a PCB and have the traces as close to the buck converter as possible. There is no ripple in the simple sense that I am observing. It is flat with randomly timed 0.5 to 1.5V spikes on the 5 volts.

Comment: Randomly timed? They are not synchronous with the switching frequency? Are you sure that your scope sampling isn't just missing some of them?  If they are truly randomly timed wrt the switching of the buck you have a different problem unrelated to the buck converter.  It can't cause random spikes.  (Have you checked your switch node jitter, and are you in continuous conduction mode or PFM mode?)

Comment: Have you put a load on the output that is representative? It may be going into over-voltage protection mode.

Comment: I know that the scope sampling is fine. I get the same type of signal regardless of the time window that I choose. The converter is supplying power to a load. Maybe because of the variability in the height of the spikes I am not seeing a synchronous pattern to the spikes? How would I tell if I am operating in one mode or another? As updated in the diagram, I am using a buck converter chip.

Comment: @Jason How about a link to that converter?

Comment: Here is the link: https://websites.godaddy.com/blob/d0f1813f-418c-4780-8b0e-f456f226885c/downloads/1bich44lo_657337.pdf

Comment: That seems OK but I have a concern that the device is shown with an input range up to 4.2 volts and not 5 volts. Have you tried lowering the supply to maybe 4 volts and see what happens?

Comment: I took it down to 4V and spikes are less but still pronounced. I had previously been using the AP3429 converter and had similar problems. In my search, I just came upon LC filters for SMPS inputs so I am going to have a go a that as a band aid. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Try and photograph a scope shot of the spike. Embed it into your question.

Comment: The scope image is attached. The input voltage was set to the 4.2V maximum for the recommended circuit. This represents a worst case image as most spikes are shorter than those shown.

Comment: An input LC filter for a buck can be problematic.  Google "Middlebrook Criterion" for more info.  Can you post a picture of the switch node waveform?  If you trigger on the switch node are the spikes synchronous or do they move around wrt the switch?

Comment: Very odd. Have you tried triggering on a spike (faster time base of course) and simultaneously displaying ch2 connected to the switching node on the chip

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Middlebrook Criterion. If I go that route, I will look for input instability. Now, educate me please. Where is the switch node in the circuit diagram, before the inductor, afterwards? I have not dived into SMPS details before. Looking at the SW output directly from the chip, the spikes do seem synchronous as they are tall enough to not be lost in the regular noise. Unfortunately.  my poor quality scope cannot trigger properly to get a good image.

Comment: The switch node is pin 3 (SW) on the IC, or the side of the inductor that connects to that pin.  The fast rise and fall times of your spike suggest inductance in the layout, as a low ESR cap would not allow the voltage to change that quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the assistance everyone. The problem was that the C1 capacitor was not properly connected due to a defect in the PCB pad or trace that resulted in an almost broken trace. Repeated attempts to change the SMD capacitor for different values had no real effect and it was only when I attempted to use a through hole capacitor soldered directly between pins Vin and GND that the spikes dropped right off. Other ad hoc attempts at adding capacitors near Vin were not very successful likely because they were not connected close enough to the chip.